# Populating a column by extracting a value from other column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `callInfo` and it looks like this:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | idUrl                                                                                                               | collectionId |                                                                                              |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | id?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=727&books.0.type=books&collectionId=20092014&type=seasonPassSource     |          |
|  2 | id:call3?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=123&books.0.type=books&collectionId=16645&type=seasonPassSource  |          |
|  3 | id:call3?maxDepth=1&parentMixId=777&type=mixSource                                                                  |          |
|  4 | idSet:call3?keyword=%22FOO%20BAR%20.%5E%24*%2B%3F%7C%28%29%7B%7D%5B%5D%22&type=wishListSource                       |          |
|  5 | idSet:call3?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=727                                                           |          |
|  6 | idSetSource.0.booksNumber=2&collectionId=16645&books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.type=books&type=seasonPassSource  |          |
|  7 | idSet:call3?keyword=hero&type=wishListSource                                                                        |          |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have created a new column called `collectionId` in the table `callInfo`, but the are many records in the table for which I need to update this column value.

I need to extract the value of `collectionId` from `idUrl` column and put it in `collectionId` column.

it should look like this

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | idUrl                                                                                                               | collectionId |                                                                                              |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | id?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=727&books.0.type=books&collectionId=20092014&type=seasonPassSource     | 20092014     |
|  2 | id:call3?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=123&books.0.type=books&collectionId=16645&type=seasonPassSource  | 16645        |
|  3 | id:call3?maxDepth=1&parentMixId=777&type=mixSource                                                                  | NULL         |
|  4 | idSet:call3?keyword=%22FOO%20BAR%20.%5E%24*%2B%3F%7C%28%29%7B%7D%5B%5D%22&type=wishListSource                       | NULL         |
|  5 | idSet:call3?books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.shopId=727                                                           | NULL         |
|  6 | idSetSource.0.booksNumber=2&collectionId=16645&books.0.levelOfDetail=high&books.0.type=books&type=seasonPassSource  | 16645        |
|  7 | idSet:call3?keyword=hero&type=wishListSource                                                                        | NULL         |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to do this in MySQL.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
UPDATE callInfo
   SET collectionId = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(idUrl, INSTR(idUrl, 'collectionId=') + 13), '&', 1)
 WHERE idUrl LIKE '%collectionId=%'
```

Output:

```
| ID | ... | COLLECTIONID |
|----| ... |--------------|
|  1 | ... |     20092014 |
|  2 | ... |        16645 |
|  3 | ... |       (null) |
|  4 | ... |       (null) |
|  5 | ... |       (null) |
|  6 | ... |        16645 |
|  7 | ... |       (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3cac/1)** demo